# Using sprintf() in C program

Tags: c, printf

When I use this method in my  C program, string doesn't print to the buffer. I tried fixing it by putting a \t in the middle of the %s's but this doesn't work for what I need.

```
char *replace_str(char *str, char *orig, char *rep)
{
  static char buffer[1000];
  char string[100];
  char *p;

  if(!(p = strstr(str, orig)))
    return str;

  p = strstr(str, orig);
  buffer[p-str] = '\0';
  strncpy(buffer, str, p-str); 
  strcpy(string, buffer);
  strcat(string,rep);
  printf("%s\n", string);
  sprintf(buffer, "%s%s", string, p+strlen(orig));
  return buffer;
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It looks OK to me, other than that you cause a buffer overflow if the strings don't fit in `buffer` and `string`. Can you update your post to show a `main()` function that demonstrates unexpected output?

Comment: It only puts the first 8 characters in string then cuts the rest off and puts the rest of p+strlen(orig)

Comment: I think It works as expected. Can you provide some example with incorrect output?

Comment: 2 thoughts: First, there is no need to call `p=strstr(str, orig)` twice. It is evaluated and the pointer assigned to `p` when the `if` statement is evaluated. Second -- what are you passing in `rep`?

Answer (score 0):

Going from the name of the function `replace_str()`, I will assume that you want to take the characters before the substring `str`, append the replacement string, and then append the characters afterwards.

The problem is the `p + strlen(orig)`.  Since `p` is assigned with `strstr(str, orig)`, it will point to a string within `orig`.  Unless this string `str` is found in the first position of `orig`, adding the length of the `orig` string to `p` will point past the string in `orig`.

What you want is:

```
sprintf(buffer, "%s%s", string, p+strlen(str));
```

This will point `p` to the first character after `str` in the original string.